# How to categorize TestNG failures based on type of failure?

Tags: testng, testng-eclipse

I'm trying to categorize TestNG failures based on the type of exception/error causing the error. Is there some way to do this? I'm relatively new to TestNG, so would appreciate any help possible

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can do this by following the below overall approach.

- Build a custom reporter implementation that implements the TestNG interface `org.testng.IReporter`
- Within this interface implementatation wherein you will get access to `ITestResult` object which represents the results of a test method and then examine its exception via `org.testng.ITestResult#getThrowable` and then include your logic to classify failures.

Here's a draft implementation

```
public class SampleReporter implements IReporter {
    @Override
    public void generateReport(List<XmlSuite> xmlSuites, List<ISuite> suites, String outputDirectory) {
        for (ISuite suite : suites) {
            Map<String, ISuiteResult> suiteResults = suite.getResults();
            for (ISuiteResult sr : suiteResults.values()) {
                ITestContext tc = sr.getTestContext();
                Set<ITestResult> failedResults = tc.getFailedTests().getAllResults();
                for (ITestResult failedResult : failedResults) {
                    Throwable throwable = failedResult.getThrowable();
                    if (throwable instanceof WebDriverException) {
                        //classify this as a selenium exception
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You can now decide to wire in this listener using one of the below options

- Using the `@Listeners` annotation on your test class.
- Using the `<listeners>` tag in your suite xml file
- Using the ServiceLoader approach

You can refer to [this](https://rationaleemotions.wordpress.com/2012/01/27/listen-to-what-i-have-to-say-about-testng-listeners/) blog post of mine to learn more about TestNG listeners in general and all the above listed ways of listener injection.